# API response is "not logged in" and I don't know why

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I try to get withdrawal fees from an exchange API:

```
s = Session()
ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
request = Request('GET', 'https://ftx.com/api//wallet/withdrawal_fee')
prepared = request.prepare()
signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new('my_api_secret'.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

prepared.headers['FTX-KEY'] = 'my_api_key'
prepared.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
prepared.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)

r = s.send(prepared).json()

print(r)
```

I tried alot, but the response is always: `{'success': False, 'error': 'Not logged in'}`

Comment: you could at least add link to this API - in question, not in comment.

Comment: you have to use single `/` in `api/wallet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo - you have to use single `/` between `api/wallet`

```
'https://ftx.com/api/wallet/withdrawal_fee'
```

And this resolves problem with `'Not logged in'` but it gives me error

```
{'success': False, 'error': 'The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'}
```

because this command needs parameters.

Something like this

```
payload = {
  "coin": "USDC",
  "size": 20.2,
  "address": "0x83a127952d266A6eA306c40Ac62A4a70668FE3BE",
  "tag": None
}

request = Request('GET', 'https://ftx.com/api/wallet/withdrawal_fee', params=payload)
```

and this gives response

```
{'success': True, 'result': {'method': 'erc20', 'fee': 2.5, 'congested': False}}
```

I got example payload from documentation [get-withdrawal-fees](https://docs.ftx.com/#get-withdrawal-fees)